# Show linechart annotations on mouseover

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm working on some google charts that show scores of apps, the issue that I'm having is that I want to add the vote count somewhere in the linechart as well, so I did some googling and thought it would be best to use annotations within my charts. So I tried that but it looks really messy.

[image]

Is there a way to make annotations show on mouseover? Or is there maybe a way to add the vote amount in the mouseover popup labels?

Code is kinda irrelevant as my code is working fine, I'm using the standard data annotation used in this documentation: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#annotating-data

Comment: [data role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) `annotation` appears on the chart, whereas `annotationText` appears on hover...

Comment: annotationText will only be shown if annotation is defined @WhiteHat

Comment: can `annotation` be blank? data role `tooltip` might work better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more into the documentation I found that

```
dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'domain'});
```

instead of

```
dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
```

Gave the result that I wanted, role: domain changes the popup title when hovering over the points which was exactly what I needed!

[image]